# Efficient ndarray operations

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I'm converting some Matlab code in Python. I need to do some matrix manipulation. My matrix (A) is (right now) a 65x3 matrix. However, the number of rows is variable depending on what step I'm at in the program.

In Matlab, the code I'm working on is:

```
output = inv(A'*A) * A';
```

The following Python code reproduces the expected output just fine. I'm just curious if there is a better (more Pythonic, faster, etc) way to do this? I'm trying to stick only to basic Python and numpy.

```
output = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.transpose(A), A)), np.transpose(A))
```

Thanks to anyone who is willing to help.

Comment: apart from using the shortcut `A.T` for transpose, you can't do much better. (but this really is just eye sugar, won't make any actual difference)

Comment: It looks like you are computing the psuedo-inverse of the matrix `A`.  Unless your application specifically needs to compute the psuedo-inverse, if you can avoid computing the inverse, then don't do it.  This article by John D. Cook should provide insight: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/.  If you are trying to find the least-squares solution to an overdetermined (or underdetermined) system of equations, use the [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) method to compute your solution directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a the `T` attribute (transposes the array). Also, if using Python 3.5, you can use `@` for the dot product (see [PEP 465](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465) for details).

```
output = np.linalg.inv(A.T @ A) @ A.T
```

Comment: Thanks. That was perfect. I knew there had to be a better way of writing it.

Comment: Note that if you are using `inv` a lot, you can do `from numpy.linalg import inv` at the beginning of your file, and then just do `output = inv(A.T @ A) @ A.T`.  Also note that this will not behave the same as the MATLAB version when working with complex numbers, in that case the MATLAB transpose is not a simple array transpose, it also takes the conjugate of the elements.